# MongoDB Aggregation join array of strings to single string

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, string-concatenation

We're trying to 'join' an array of strings to a single string within an aggregation.

Given is the following dataset:

Collection 1:

```
{
  id: 1234,
  field: 'test'
}
```

Collection 2:

```
{
  id: 1111,
  collection1_id: 1234,
  name: 'Max'
},
{
  id: 1112,
  collection1_id: 1234,
  name: 'Andy'
}
```

The current result (after lookup etc.):

```
{
  id: 1234,
  field: 'test',
  collection2: ['Max', 'Andy'] 
}
```

**The desired result:**

```
{
  id: 1234,
  field: 'test',
  collection2: 'Max, Andy'
}
```

Is it somehow possible to join the 'collection2' to a single string? We've tried with `$concat` but it only accepts strings.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You were on the right track.

Just add [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce) over [$concat](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/#exp._S_concat) in your `$project` stage.

```
'collection2': {
    '$reduce': {
        'input': '$collection2',
        'initialValue': '',
        'in': {
            '$concat': [
                '$$value',
                {'$cond': [{'$eq': ['$$value', '']}, '', ', ']}, 
                '$$this']
        }
    }
}
```

Note: We use [$cond](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) to prevent a leading `,` in the concatenation. 
You could also use [$substrCP](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) before `$reduce` as an alternative to `$cond`.

Comment: Any solution for mongo 3.2?  I don't have access to `$reduce`

Comment: @Friedrich May you please elaborate more on how one may use `$substrCP`?

Answer (score 4):

Starting `Mongo 4.4`, the `$group` stage has a new aggregation operator [`$accumulator`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/accumulator/#accumulator-aggregation) allowing custom accumulations of documents as they get grouped:

```
// { "collectionId" : 1234, "name" : "Max"  }
// { "collectionId" : 876,  "name" : "Rob"  }
// { "collectionId" : 1234, "name" : "Andy" }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $group: {
    _id: "$collectionId",
    names: {
      $accumulator: {
        accumulateArgs: ["$name"],
        init: function() { return [] },
        accumulate: function(names, name) { return names.concat(name) },
        merge: function(names1, names2) { return names1.concat(names2) },
        finalize: function(names) { return names.join(",") },
        lang: "js"
      }
    }
  }}
])
// { "_id" : 876,  "names" : "Rob"      }
// { "_id" : 1234, "names" : "Max,Andy" }
```

The accumulator:

- accumulates on the field `name` (`accumulateArgs`)
- is initialised to an empty array (`init`)
- accumulates by concatenating new names to already seen names (`accumulate` and `merge`)
- and finally joins all names as a string (`finalize`)

Answer (score 0):

To flatten this array, you need to shift process to client.

mongo will provide some new flattening options in new edition, but afaik it will be arithmetic ones (avg, min, max....).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's easiest to use JavaScript:

```
db.getCollection('Collection1').aggregate([
{
   $lookup:
     {
       from: 'Collection2',
       localField: 'id',
       foreignField: 'collection1_id',
       as: 'col2'
     }
}]).map((e) => ({
  id: e.id,
  field: e.field,
 collection2: Array.isArray(e.col2) &&
   e.col2.reduce((arr, el) => {
     arr.push(el.name);
    return arr;
  }, []).join(', ')
}))
```