# MongoDB: aggregation, array of objects to string value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My question is pretty similar to: [MongoDB Aggregation join array of strings to single string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38377582/mongodb-aggregation-join-array-of-strings-to-single-string), but instead of pure Array, like: `['Batman', 'Robin']` I have Array of objects:

```
_id: 1,
field_value: [
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "Batman"
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    name: "Robin"
  }
]
```

I am trying to use [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/#exp._S_reduce) but got error instead.

I want to receive the following result:

```
  _id: 1,
  field_value: "Batman, Robin" /** <= String value */
```

or at least array of property values:

```
  _id: 1,
  field_value: ["Batman", "Robin"] /** <= Array of strings (name property) */
```

My [MongoPlayground data example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/TTT2zAd0mX5)

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62346889/mongodb-how-to-flatten-some-query-results/62347449#62347449 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the same approach with `$reduce`, `$$this` represents a single `field_value` entity so you need `$$this.name`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            field_value: {
                $reduce: {
                    input: "$field_value",
                    initialValue: "",
                    in: {
                        $concat: [
                            "$$value",
                            { $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$$value", "" ] }, "", "," ] },
                            { $toString: "$$this.name" }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/2NBsDGo9sWf)

Comment: Yes, this exactly what I need it too. I also updated my question with MongoPlayground example data. So the real question is: I can accept is as an answer to the question (*and I will do it, by default*), or should I delete the whole question, because it's a duplicate?

Comment: You can accept since you were asking about an array of objects